# facebook open graph story id returning null

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-opengraph

```
 [FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"me"
                                       graphObject:object
                                 completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                     id result,
                                                     NSError *error) {
                                     // handle the result
                                     if(!error){
                                         NSLog(@" id %@",result);
                                         NSMutableDictionary<FBGraphObject> *action = [FBGraphObject graphObject];
                                         action[@"frame_pack"] = @"http://samples.ogp.me/669674679792128";

                                         [FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"me/com_scandino_photify:buy"
                                                                            graphObject:action
                                                                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                                                          id result,
                                                                                          NSError *error) {
                                                    NSLog(@" id 2 %@",result);                   // handle the result
                                                                      }];
                                     }else{NSLog(@" id %@",result);
                                         NSLog(@" errooooorrrr%@",error);}
                                 }];
```

everything goes well, publish actions permission is granted. No error showing, but graph story is not posting. code is given. here id return true and id 2 returns Null.

Comment: What is the error when the id 2 is null?

Comment: no single error is shown. everything goes fine. but still not posting on facebook